# Как объединить два wifi роутера в одну сеть?

Tags: сеть, wifi, роутер

Помогите, пожалуйста.Имеется - Dlink DSL 2600 U - используется для подключения к ADSL.- Dlink DIR 655 - объединяет офисные компьютеры в сеть. Основное назначение, это усиление сигнала.Задача объединить эти два роутера, для доступа офисных компьютеров в интернет. Возможно ли это?Вот примитивная схема того, что нужно получить:![схема][1]П.С. В последствии требуется настроить проброс портов из интернета, на один из компьютеров в сети, поэтому оптимальным было бы сделать второй роутер полностью прозрачным.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3pQL.png

Comment: а в чем проблема? подключаешь их между собой и настройку проброса делаешь тут DSL 2600 U, а  ADSL Dlink DIR 655 выступает в качестве коммутатора, или я чето не понял)

Comment: Вы не поняли. Во-первых, в DIR 655 нет adsl. Он просто wifi роутер.Как вариант подключал компьютеры по wifi к DIR 655, а его подключал к DSL 2600. Возникла другая проблема, компьютеры ходят в интернет с максимальной скоростью, которую выдает провайдер 8мб/с, а вот между собой в локальной сети они общаются на 1мб/с и не больше.

Comment: Еще подключал отдельно локалку через DIR655. А в интернет отдельной сетью через DSL2600. Объединял две сетки в мост, но тогда либо локалка не работает, либо интернет.

Comment: НАстроить можно, разбирайся с момента "либо интернет"

Comment: Если мостом сделать DIR-655, то скорость упадёт однозначно, потому что роутить тогда будет DSL-2600, через WiFi. Значит, мостом надо ставить именно DSL-2660 тогда DIR-655 будет роутить непосредственно по локалке!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решал этот вопрос только перепрошивкой на DDWRT, стандартная прошивка DIR такого не умеет, чтоб прозрачный был доступ, доступ только по IP.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибкой было говорить "или я чето не понял" )) я всё понял, нужно один из *Dlink DIR 655* настроить в режим коммутатора, его аплинк соединить с локальным портом второго *Dlink DIR 655*, затем уже *Dlink DSL 2600 U* и Инет.

Wi-fi настроить одинаково на двух *Dlink DIR 655* - всё!

На счёт падения скорости нужно будет разбираться после - это совсем другая задача.

Comment: К сожалению, второго DIR655 нет. Есть один DIR655 и один DSL2600

Comment: чёрт, невнимательно прочитал задание.. если *Dlink DIR 655* используется для усиления, то очевидно, что его одного нужно настроить в режим коммутатора и аплинком воткнуть в клиенский порт *Dlink DSL 2600 U*, а *Dlink DSL 2600 U* будет отрабатывать, как роутер и первый (или всё равно какой) по очереди wi-fi.

Answer (score 1):

А можно и двойной роутинг сделать (у меня работает, но сделал по другой причине):Пусть первый роутер даёт второму фиксированный адрес, скажем 10.10.10.2. А второй этот адрес ловит, и распределяет уже по 192.168.0... Правда, в таком случае проброс портов сложнее. Лучше всё же первый мостом включить!